# Bash decrease all integers in delimited file by one

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a space delimited file that contains only integers. Each line has different number of integers starting from 1. Is there a way with an one liner awk, sed, grep or any combination to actually create another file which will be exactly the same with all integers decreased by one? There are also no empty lines on this file.

Input file example:

```
2 3 4 5 6 7
1 3 5
```

Output file example:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
0 2 4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this awk command,

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){$i=$i-1}}1' infile > outfile
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file
2 3 4 5 6 7
1 3 5

4 4 5
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){$i=$i-1}}1' file
1 2 3 4 5 6
0 2 4

3 3 4
```

Comment: Perfect. I upvoted your answer. I will accept it as well

Answer (score 2):

You could do this in a Bash loop by reading each line of the file into an array.

```
while read -ra line; do
    for i in ${!line[@]}; do
        let line[$i]--
    done
    echo ${line[@]}
done < file > output_file
```

Comment: And this seems pretty complicated, as well. Still it is good to learn new things. +1 for you effort.

Answer (score 1):

```
for DD in $(cat your_input_file|tr " " ",")
do
   for x in $(echo $DD | tr "," " ")
   do
      let m=$x-1
      echo -n " $m" >>your_output_file
   done
   echo >>your_output_file
done
```

**but @Avinash Raj's suggestion is better**

Comment: Seems complicated. Still +1 for you effort.

Comment: The UNIX shell is an environment from which to call tools. The standard UNIX tool to manipulate the contents of a text file is awk. Any time you find yourself writing a loop in shell to manipulate the contents of a text file you have the wrong approach and the end result is invariably longer, more complicated, slower, and/or less robust than an awk solution.

Comment: @Ed Morton, I totally agree with you. However there is quite big class of problem, when you need both manipulate with text files and run some procedures. So it is useful to keep in mind that you can do  same manipulations in shell also, but you right, it is awkward.

Answer (score 1):

A `perl` version:

```
perl -pe 's/(\d+)/$1-1/eg' file
1 2 3 4 5 6
0 2 4
```

**Explanation:**

- `-p` assume `while (<>) { ... }` loop around program and prints the line too, like sed.
- `-e` executes the code
- `s/(\d+)/$1-1/eg` is a simple substitution where we group each number and perform subtraction to it. `e` flag evaluates the substitution. `g` flag performs global substitution.

Comment: +1, while being a Pythonista myself, always love a grandpa `perl` solution ;-)